# Unassiged variable not undefined implicitly

Tags: typescript

Why is the below code not causing a compile error?

To break it down I'm creating an unassigned variable, which will be undefined at first, later on I am defining it. But in between I created a function to trim my string. Inside the function `str` is undefined and if run it will cause an error, but Typescript is not helping me and why is that?

I could've wrote `let str: string | undefined;` in the first line which will guard me against the possible undefined situation, but why isn't this implicit when the variable isn't defined?

```js
let str: string;

const strTrimmer = () => {
    str.trim();
};

strTrimmer();

str = ' abc ';
```

I am running Typescript in strict mode.

Answer (score 1):

Your type should be the source of truth. There is a different between `let str: string;` and `let str: string | undefined`. In the first case, you really want str not to be `undefined`, that make no error in your `strTrimmer()`, which is not the case of `let str: string | undefined`. However, it is not possible for typescript to know that `strTrimmer()` should not be called before `str` assignment

```js
let str: string;

str.trim(); // Error: used before being assigned
str = 'abc';
str.trim(); // OK
const strTrimmer = () => {
    str.trim(); // OK because we tell typescript that str is always a string
};
```

```js
let str: string | undefined;

str.trim(); // Error: used before being assigned
str = 'abc';
str.trim(); // OK since typescript know that str is a string
const strTrimmer = () => {
    str.trim(); // Error: object is possibility undefined. Typescript can not know when this function is called, so the str could be undefined
};
```

Comment: "*Your type should be the source of truth. There is a different between `let str: string;` and `let str: string | undefined`*" I agree with this but it's still odd that `let str: string;` is allowed, since the declaration is wrong - I would expect an error from TS. A correct declaration should either be `let str: string | undefined;` or `let str: string = "";`.

Comment: I understand, but it would be too strict because you may assign it later.  It's easy for a string, but what if you have a complex type instead?

Comment: I'd say that you do `MyType | null` or `MyType | undefined` explicitly. After all `let x: MyType;` is still *wrong* as it doesn't represent the correct value - `x` does **not** hold `MyType`. We both agree that `let str: string;` is not actually a string, so TS should really not allow it in strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript does not know if you call `strTrimmer` before or after you assigned `str`, therefore it is not throwing an error.

That said... it's more elegant to add a parameter to `strTrimmer`, since that makes it reusable, and, more importantly, it allows typescript to spot your unassigned variable.

Like this:

```
let str: string;

const strTrimmer: (a_sString: string) => string = (a_sString) => {
    return a_sString.trim();
};

str = strTrimmer(str); // Variable 'str' is used before being assigned(2454)

str = ' abc ';
```